# Querying Oracle Clob datatype

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

how do I query a table for a column that is clob type? I need to query the table for the column for a certain string (in addition to other conditions - I might need to use Case statement), my initial idea was to query the data in the sub-query and then find a match using Case in the top query. however I am now stuck as I am not sure how to query clob type data in Select!

Edit:
the clob column in the table is set of paragraphs, and the string I am trying to search for may be in any location in the paragraph. And I am unsure of the size of the clob.

Comment: Length of clob:   Select length(...clob expr...) from ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this examples illustrates clearly what i am trying to explain.

```
SET SQLBL ON;
SET DEFINE OFF;

CREATE TABLE CLOB_TEST
(
clob_in CLOB
);

INSERT
INTO CLOB_TEST VALUES
  (
    'I am working as a DBA and senior database resource in L&T Infotech in Pune India'
  );


SELECT DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(CLOB_IN,3000) ot FROM CLOB_TEST;

-----------------------------OUTPUT------------------------------------------

OT
I am working as a DBA and senior database resource in L&T Infotech in Pune India

-----------------------------OUTPUT------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I get an error when I try this: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Answer (score 0):

In many respects, the same way you "query a column" (odd terminology!) of type varchar2.

table structure:

```
SQL> describe t
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ------------------------- -------- --------------------------------------------
 COL1                               VARCHAR2(20)
 COL2                               CLOB
```

table content:

```
SQL> select * from t;

COL1                 COL2
-------------------- -------------------------------------------------------
abc                  afdreed
azx;                 ffare21
```

query the table (where clause on the CLOB column):

```
SQL> select * from t where col2 like '%dre%';

COL1                 COL2
-------------------- -----------------------------------------------------------
abc                  afdreed
```

Comment: I am not sure if you read my question completely. I need to list the column separately in my select statement and I am not able to do so.

Comment: I don't understand. In my select statement I listed col2 separately, which is a column of CLOB data type. Perhaps you can give an example of exactly what you are trying to do and is not working?

Comment: I am trying for something like this: select case when col2 like '%abc%' then ABC from (select col2 from t where .......) does this help? this is because I first need to query a subset of the data and then display it based on the case.

Comment: And what doesn't work? What you described so far should work just fine! Post the query that fails and the error message.

Comment: when I run the query as described above I get the following error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB. After some research it seems I may need to use dbms_lob.substr() however, I do not know how to use this function or the max size of the clob.

Comment: Can you post the query instead of describing it? The mistake may very well be somewhere else, not where you think.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have a look on the package DBMS_LOB ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i997432)). It has some functions useful for working with LOB

for example:

- [Substr](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i999349)  - The function returns amount bytes or characters of a LOB, starting from an absolute offset from the beginning of the LOB.
- [Insrt](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i998546) - This function returns the matching position of the nth occurrence of the pattern in the LOB, starting from the offset you specify.
- [GetLength](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i998484) - This function gets the length of the specified LOB. The length in bytes or characters is returned.
- [Trim](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i999503) - This procedure trims the value of the internal LOB to the length you specify in the newlen parameter. Specify the length in bytes for BLOBs, and specify the length in characters for CLOBs.

Also you can try to work with string functions. Some of them are able to work with not huge lob files.