# How to parse and display data using SQL from a column with CLOB data type

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm currently trying to retrieve and parse `clob` data using SQL. The Data stored as:

```
---- -------- ------------- 
ID   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(150) 
REC           CLOB
```

The delimiter for each record is 'þ'

An example record would be:

```
ABCCAU1780MþþGTLTþEMS-LOGINþ15543þ67320þþþ1.2þþþ3þþþ15543þ67882þ15543þ67888þþGþ1þGENRELþþþþ5
```

Is there a way to retrieve and display this as columns using SQL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Querying Oracle Clob datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611520/querying-oracle-clob-datatype)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have something like this on mind?

```
select * From test;

ID  REC
--  ---------------------------------------------------
01  ABCCAU1780MþþGTLTþEMS-LOGINþ15543þ67320þþþ
02  1.2þþþ3þþþ15543þ67882þ15543þ67888þþGþ1þGENRELþþþþ5
```

Then:

```
select id, 
  replace(regexp_substr(replace(rec, 'þ', 'þ#'), '[^þ]+', 1, column_value), '#', '') val
from test 
cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
                               connect by level <= regexp_count(rec, 'þ') + 1
                              ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
order by id, column_value;

ID  VAL
--  ------------------------
01  ABCCAU1780M
01  
01  GTLT
01  EMS-LOGIN
01  15543
01  67320
01  
01  
01  
02  1.2
02  
02  
02  3
02  
02  
02  15543
02  67882
02  15543
02  67888
02  
02  G
02  1
02  GENREL
02  
02  
02  
02  5
```

Comment: Sort of, I created a query a similar query, but there are problems with the ordering when there are no values inside the delimiter.

Comment: with
fields_to_rows as
(
SELECT 
    CB_SCH.ID,
    c1.column_value as key,
    cast(regexp_substr(CB_SCH.REC,'[^\þ\]+',1,c1.column_value) as varchar2(200)) as fname
    FROM 
    CB_SCH,
    TABLE(
     cast(multiset(SELECT LEVEL FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 0.5 * LENGTH (REGEXP_REPLACE(CB_SCH.REC,'{^\ý\}+') ) ) as sys.ODCINUMBERLIST)) c1 
 )
SELECT * from fields_to_rows 
pivot ( max(fname)for ( key ) in (1 as C1,2 as C2,12 as C12,15 as C15,16 as C16));

Comment: No problems in sorting with my query. I suggest you use / apply it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, here is the [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e1d11/2)

```
select 
   DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(REC,3000)
from yourTable
```